# SQL Calculate Working Days Lost In a week, month etc

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the number of work days last based on a period of absence.

My data looks like this:

```
PersonKey   AbsenceType StartDate   EndDate ExpectedEndDate AbsenceDays AbsenceHours    AbsenceReason   AbsenceStartType    AbsenceEndType  DaysLost    TimeLost
2036612BSL  Sickness    2022-09-14  2022-09-16  NULL    NULL    NULL    Infections  FULL    FULL    1.00    8.00
```

I figured something like this would work:

```
SELECT PersonKey
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(DaysLost)
        WHERE GETUTCDATE() BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, - (DATEPART(dw, GETUTCDATE()) - 1), GETUTCDATE())
                AND DATEADD(dd, 7 - (DATEPART(dw, GETUTCDATE()) - 1), GETUTCDATE())
        ) 'Days Lost This Week'
FROM ODS.MyViewAbsence
WHERE PersonKey = '2036612BSL'
GROUP BY PersonKey
```

However in hindsight I need to calculate the number of days between the StartDate and EndDate and then only count the days of that period that exist with the current week?

That is what I'm not too sure about.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your database or company already have a calendar table somewhere? This is very useful for this type of problem, and is often necessary for other things like fiscal periods etc, so a lot of times one exists somewhere already so we don't have to generate one

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Several product specific functions used above.)

Comment: @Josh I do have a calendar table yes

Comment: @jarlh MSFT SQL

Answer (score 0):

Using some type of recurrent job, create a Calendar table with one row per day, where you can mark workdays and holidays. Then you'd be able to easily select the number of workdays between two dates.

Answer (score 0):

Having a calendar table is really useful for this situation. If you don't have one, you must generate one, which can be done on-the-fly but many companies will actually have one somewhere if you ask around. It might even contain the business day flag and holiday flags that you need to do this properly.

Here's some SQL to get you started. Note that you'll want to look at your calendar table and come up with the best logic based on that internal data.

I provided a 2nd option which just counts Mon-Fri but that obviously doesn't care about holidays, so it's less than ideal.

```
SELECT A.PersonKey
    ,COUNT(1) AS DAYS_LOST
    ,SUM(C.WORKING_DAY_FLAG) AS BUSINESS_DAYS_LOST
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,C.CALENDAR_DATE) > 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BUSINESS_DAYS_LOST_2
FROM ODS.MyViewAbsence A
INNER JOIN {{ calendar_table }} C
ON C.CALENDAR_DATE < A.EndDate
AND C.CALENDAR_DATE >= A.StartDate
WHERE PersonKey = '2036612BSL'
GROUP BY PersonKey
```

I'm not familiar w/ what version of MSSQL you're on, but if for some reason you aren't allowed to make a join like that, an alternative might be to write the join old-school in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT A.PersonKey
    ,COUNT(1) AS DAYS_LOST
    ,SUM(C.WORKING_DAY_FLAG) AS BUSINESS_DAYS_LOST
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,C.CALENDAR_DATE) > 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS BUSINESS_DAYS_LOST_2
FROM ODS.MyViewAbsence A, {{ calendar_table }} C
WHERE C.CALENDAR_DATE < A.EndDate
AND C.CALENDAR_DATE >= A.StartDate
AND PersonKey = '2036612BSL'
GROUP BY PersonKey
```

Comment: watch out cause DATEPART(dw) is not deterministic and depends on @@datefirst settings, so 6 isn't always saturday